# Stripe checkout: unable to retrieve token

Tags: java, html, forms, web-services, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make charge with Stripe, using checkout to create a token.
This is my HTML code taken from the basic example:

```
<form action="ws/stripe/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{MY_TEST_PK}"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Abcdf S.r.l."
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="eur">
  </script>
</form>
```

And this is the web service I wrote, that simply should print the token retrieved:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/stripe")
public class ChargeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/charge", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void charge(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Stripe.apiKey = "{MY_TEST_SK}";

    String token = request.getParameter("stripeToken");
    System.out.println("TOKEN: " + token);
```

This doesn't work, maybe the problem is the path written inside the attribute action? I'm pretty new to HTML development.

Comment: Try to change @RequestMapping(value = "/stripe") to @RequestMapping(value = "stripe")

Comment: Thanks for reply, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try to use AJAX call for POST from HTML